# How can I wrap or break long text/word in a fixed width span?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a span with a fixed width that when I type any thing in the span like `<span>lgasdfjksdajgdsglkgsadfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasddkgjk</span>`, a long string of non-spaced text, the word(s) break or wrap to next line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `word-wrap:break-word;`, which will break words if they are too long for your span width.

```css
span { 
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<span>VeryLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongExample</span>
```

Comment: Adding `white-space: normal` helps to override outer styling that may get in the way :) .. `inline-block` works as well as `block`

Comment: What about breaking two spans which are inside a block element?

Comment: For those still having trouble after using this answer, be sure to specify a 'width' otherwise it may not work

Comment: It needs to have a width in order to know where to break

Comment: For those still having trouble after using this answer AND specifying 'width', check that there is no 'white-space: nowrap' prop present, otherwise it won't work

Comment: doesn't work in my case: <span>......................................................................................</span> it doesn't break the dots.

Comment: flex not work, see https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/pen/WNGXqeZ

Comment: It works when I do width as a certain number of pixels but not as a %. Any insights?

Comment: @katia made a good point about setting white-space: normal, turned out getting rid of white-space: nowrap was all I needed to do

Answer (score 77):

Try following css with addition of `white-space`:

```css
span {
    display: block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 50px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out why my text was never wrapping! white-space was the reason.

Comment: My issue was also fixed once I put: `white-space: normal`

Comment: Here is a reference table in case you need white-space and wrapping: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: This worked:  
`<span style="color: gray; word-wrap:break-word;">loong text</span>`

Answer (score 18):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bkA4m/1/)**

```
  li span{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: my friend I want when put span width:50px; values in my span only show in 50px and other values go on to next line and show in 50px!!!

Comment: @mamal10 Check Maxime Lorant's solution.

Answer (score 3):

By default a `span` is an `inline` element... so that's not the default behavior.

You can make the `span` behave that way by adding `display: block;` to your CSS.

```
span {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
span {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the pratical scope of the question and as an appendix to the given answers: 
Sometimes one might find it necessary to specify the selectors a little bit more.

By defining the the full span as *display:inline-block* you might have a hard time displaying images.

Therefore I prefer to define a span like so:

```
span {
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  word-wrap:break-word;      
}
p span, a span,
h1 span, h2 span, h3 span, h4 span, h5 span {
  display:inline-block;
}
img{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, display: block was breaking the design as intended.

The `max-width` property just saved me.

and for styling, you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` as well.

my code was

```
max-width: 255px
overflow:hidden
```