# Text going off Show Page Rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a text_area for users to type a paragraph. Their paragraph on the show page is all in one line, and therefore goes off the page. What is the easiest way to keep it all contained in one area.

I have everything wrapped in a well, and also some bootstrap columns, yet the text still goes out.

```
<div class="well" style="background:white">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:40px; text-align:center">
      <p style="font-size: 100pt;"><font color="red"><strong><%= comment.commenter %></strong></font></p><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" style="margin-top:40px; text-align:left">
      <p><strong>Tell us about it:</strong></p><br>
      <p><%= comment.body %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<%= comment.body %>` is what is going off of the page. I know this is probably simple, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I wrap or break long text/word in a fixed width span?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225302/how-can-i-wrap-or-break-long-text-word-in-a-fixed-width-span)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not a Rails issue. This is a simple CSS issue.

Give the paragraph a class:

```
.comment-body {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Now it won't break:

```
<p class='comment-body'><%= comment.body %></p>
```