# Show hidden text on hover with animation

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <span>asd</span> adsafsadlvjnsd
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  width: 0;
}
li:hover span {
  width: 60px;
}
```

This means that the content in the span is initially hidden but shown when the item is hovered, currently if the content on the li is too big it simply pushes the content down, is there a way to only push as much content as necessary? I tried using word-break but that didn't seem to work.

Also, I want to have the slide animation when hovering.

Comment: How that fiddle show what you want? it's just an input field, no hover effect anywhere, you want to break the lines on the input? use textarea or div contenteditable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `width: auto;` instead of fixed width on hover.

```css
span {
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover span {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>hello</span> world
  </li>
</ul>
```

For continuous text you can apply `white-space: nowrap;`. For animation you probably need to use some Javascript if the span can't be fixed width, since the current CSS doesn't allow to use `auto` width / height for transition. Below I use jQuery to get the width of the span.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhadgvcd/)**

```js
spanWidth = $('li span').width();
$('li span').css('width', '0');

$('li').hover(
  function() {
    $('span', this).css('width', spanWidth);
  },
  function() {
    $('span', this).css('width', '0');
  }
);
```

```css
/*hide the span, works together with the script*/
span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
}
/*get rid of the extra whitespace, use it as needed*/
span { margin-right: -4px; }
li:hover span { margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu tincidunt velit. Nam gravida venenatis mollis. Cras sed lacus varius, pretium nulla eget, auctor diam. Suspendisse ullamcorper ex nisi, non scelerisque lorem pellentesque id. Mauris non bibendum libero, vel efficitur lorem.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to use word-break but by default span's are considered inline and hence they must be changed to **display:block** for it to work.
The code should be as follows:

```
span { 
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

More information can be gained from this old thread: [How can I wrap or break long text/word in a fixed width span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225302/how-can-i-wrap-or-break-long-text-word-in-a-fixed-width-span)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Your code must work just pushing the text to the right not down, I guess you are changing other properties like making the span `block` wich will push the other text down.

Check this snippet using `inline-block`:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  transition:width .5s linear;
}
li:hover span {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Hidden Content</span> 
    Donec pulvinar magna quis urna euismod rhoncus. Nunc et mauris quis ex rhoncus semper. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec non nisl metus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin eu convallis dui. Vestibulum commodo feugiat mauris, facilisis cursus erat tempor iaculis. Aliquam lorem tortor, placerat at malesuada ac, porta feugiat risus.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I edited the post with the full code, the problem occurs when a really long word (or just a bunch of @'s with no spaces) is typed, in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap) example a really long word is cut and continues on the next line, but that's not happening with my code.