# Vaadin 14 Label/span/text line break in word if exceed max width

Tags: components, vaadin, vaadin14

is there any option to continue one word in other line if it length exceed max width?
In my code line breaks are working correctly when word isnt long enough to exceed max width. when i have too long word in my text component then it is drawing outside the layout area.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225302/how-can-i-wrap-or-break-long-text-word-in-a-fixed-width-span ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I wrap or break long text/word in a fixed width span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225302/how-can-i-wrap-or-break-long-text-word-in-a-fixed-width-span)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

worked for me