# Span tooltip is not showing the long text in new line

Tags: html, css, frontend, hover, tooltip

I am creating an image slider where in there will be images with text-box. The text-box will have a title with the actual title. But the actual title is too long so i am using tooltip to display the long text when we hover over the text-box

Issue i am facing here is that the text is not displayed on new line and only shows partially[image: see the image]

The tooltip should show entire text in new lines but pointing to the same title. I checked online and found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225302/how-can-i-wrap-or-break-long-text-word-in-a-fixed-width-span) and followed first answer but after that the text shows half. It should show entire text like "Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere" on new lines but pointing to same title.

See the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style5.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <center>
              <div class="image">
                <div class="image-box"><img class="image-cont" src=""></img></div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p>Product title</p>
                    <span id="tooltiptext">Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</span>
                    <p class="title">Electrolux EENB54EB Ultraenergica Classic Aspirapolvere</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="image">
                <div class="image-box"><img class="image-cont" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PhUckHB3L.jpg"></img></div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p>Product title</p>
                    <p>Curtain</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="image">
                <div class="image-box"><img class="image-cont" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/518Se4188mL.jpg"></img></div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p>Product title</p>
                    <p>Curtain</p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="image">
                <div class="image-box"><img class="image-cont" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51PhUckHB3L.jpg"></img></div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <p>Product title</p>
                    <p>Curtain</p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Css code:

```
.image-container {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px; 
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.image-box{
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.image-cont{
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
}

.text-box{
    padding:0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 5px;
    border-top: 2px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer
}

#tooltiptext{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  word-break:break-all;

  /*visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;*/
}

#tooltiptext::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  border: 15px solid;
  border-color: #0000 #0000 #000 #0000;
}


.text-box:hover #tooltiptext{
  top: -130;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 
}
```

NOTE: tooltiptext is the element in question here which should show the entire text in lines below but pointing to the same image.
I am not familiar with css at all and struggling with these simple tasks. :(
any help would be appreciated

Additional info: When i select text, i can see i is hidden in same line. See the image: https://ibb.co/rG0MHVc .. since i was unable to add photo, added a link here

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` prevents a long text (`#tooltiptext`) from *wrapping* to next line.

Comment: I removed that white-space: nowrap rene but still same issue, it comes in a single line itself. Can you please help?

Comment: I removed white-space: nowrap and added white-space:notmal which fixed that issue but now i am facing another issue :(